# Flash upload progress

Tags: actionscript, upload, arrays, bandwidth, filereference

I'm making a bandwidth test in flash, and I want to display a progress bar and the current calculated speed. For the download part this is pretty straightforward, but for the upload part it gets a bit trickier.
As I've understood the only way to track upload progress is by using FileReference. But as I'm uploading a dynamically generated ByteArray, it seems FileReference isn't usable either.

So one idea I had, was just uploading a ByteArray of say 100-200 kB, and calculate the speed of that upload, then fake a progress bar based on that speed, when uploading a larger ByteArray. But then again it would probably be way off under some circumstances, and calculating the current speed would be difficult.

So I need some ideas on how to solve this :)

Answer (score 0):

Best way is to look at code that already does this.  Go [here](http://weblog.cahlan.com/files/FileUpload/FileUploadApp.html) to see an example.  View source is enabled so right-click and look at what they're doing.